# OpenCV: Fixed Size Error for fitLine() Function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently using OpenCV's `fitLine()` function.

This is my code:

```
float lineParams[16];
Mat lineParamsMat(Size(4,4), CV_32F, lineParams);
Point2f points[6];

//point parameters for line
Mat point_mat(Size(1, 6), CV_32FC2, points);

//The line is stored in a row in the lineParamsMat Matrix
fitLine (point_mat, lineParamsMat.row(i), CV_DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
```

The error occurs in the last line. The error message, clear as always, is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in create, file /Applications/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2232
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Applications/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2232: error: (-215) !fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows) in function create
```

Has anyone faced this error before?

Comment: Can you use a `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` and `cv::Vec4f` instead of the two `Mat`s? That worked for me. The issue will have something to do with how you structure one of the `Mat`s. Seeing the stack trace would help shed more light on what it actually is.

Comment: That's a good idea- I will try it! How can I view a more detailed stack trace?

Comment: Run it in a debugger and make it stop when the exception is thrown. The exact process depends on the tools you're using. You will need debugging symbols for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that changing lineParamsMat.row() to lineParamsMat.col() works!